# Book: kids/teenagers fighting (maybe purple) aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read this book in middle school. It was somewhere in the time span of 1970's to early 2000's. The book revolves around these kids fighting aliens in space that have incredible technological advantages over the humans and then the kids gain control of some of their technology and use it. I believe it is a two part series but I cant remember. The book starts out with the kids training in space and they get attacked. Its not *Ender’s Game*.

Comment: Please take a look at the guidelines under story-identification in the tag I added to your question. It will help to guide you to add additional details.

Comment: That's a long stretch in middle school.